# How to stop jquery function while navigating/reloading to other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have used following `jquery` functions to making `Ajax` request periodically in `rails` view

```
<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ $.get("/simulations/<%= @simulation.id %>"); }, 5000);
});
```

This functions works perfectly. But when I am navigating to other page by clicking back button it still running (confirmed by checking `chrome developer console`)

It stopped if i reload the page. How to make it stop while navigating to other pages?

## edit-1

After suggestion

```
<script>
$(function() {
   var interval =  setInterval(function(){ $.get("/simulations/<%= @simulation.id %>"); }, 5000);

    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is a standard javascript function that returns a number representing an interval id that can be passed to clearInterval to be cancelled.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ $.get("/simulations/<%= @simulation.id %>"); }, 5000);

    // elsewhere ...

    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain it through code. I am new to jquery

Comment: I edited in an example for you. setInterval/clearInterval are not jQuery functions fyi.

Comment: Actually It's still running in the background

Comment: Are you *sure* you passed the returned interval id to clearInterval()? If you pass it null or undefined it will not alert you that nothing was stopped.

Comment: Please checkout the `edit-1` section in question. I did and it's not making any request even if I am on the current page. I checked the dev console and there is no request going from that page

Comment: The code in your edit will start, and then immediately stop your poller. I don't think that is what you intended. You need to call clearInterval when you navigate to another page.

Comment: Ah! got it
Is there any way to figure out that we navigate to other page from javascript?